# Store proxy extraparams retrieve record

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, store

I need to send some data to a store proxy and instead of reloading the store I just want to get that record. Can this be done?

```
 var newRecord =  documentStore.getProxy().extraParams = {id:element.data.id};
```

Something like above which of course doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If that data/record is already loaded in store then you can get it using [`store.findRecord()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findRecord) or [`store.getById()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getById) methods.

But if you want record which is not loaded/available in store, then you will need to reload your store with required values(filter).

**Update :**

Well, you can capture the [`itemclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick) or [`cellclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick) event for first grid, and load the second grid store with passing required filter parameters OR you can create AJAX request, get the response and build the record and add it to other store.

Comment: It is not in the store, I need to get it without reloading the store

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you are trying to do? I mean functionality

Comment: I have two grids. On an item click I would like to load a new element, and add it to another grid(multi select). Is there any way to send multiple ids to the store?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy on your Model you can use the static "load" method, ie if you have a model "Contact" you would do this:

```
Contact.load("ID_VALUE", {
     scope: this,
     callback: function (record, operation, success) {
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to select a record from one list of items, retrieve additional data for that selected item, and then have that item be added to an existing store.

Please correct me if this is wrong. But, going on this assumption, you could have a load method on a Model as **bhutten** has suggested. On the return of the model (i.e. callback), you would then add that Model to the Store via the Ext.data.Store.add(model) method. This would add the record to the data store without reloading all of the data in the store.

Perhaps a more elegant approach could be creating your own store (i.e myApp.store.MyStore) that extends the Ext.data.Store. Then, create your own method that accepts an identifier (or multiple identifiers) that could load models to the Store without reloading the entire store.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore' {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  requires: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
  model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
  loadMyModel: function (id) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'someurl',
      params: {id: id},
      success: function (resp) {
        var myModel = null; // parse response into MyModel
        this.add(myModel);
      },
      scope: this
    });
  }
});
```